# CGRect Assistant?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, interface-builder, cgrect

This is a little vague, but i'll try to be specific.

How do you use CGRect and CGRectMake? Is there an assistant or something which you can use to find points quickly? I've looked in Interface Builder, but it seems to me that there is no quick way of finding the points to use in CGRect. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be great.

Comment: Finding what points to use? With CGRectMake you just create a rectangle using 4 points, the x,y origin and the width and height. `CGRectMake(0,0,5,5)` <- 5x5 rect that starts at 0,0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to recreate an interface in code that's in interface builder, you need to look at the Size Inspector:

First, select an element in interface builder:

[image]

Now look at the Size Inspector in the right-side panel:

[image]

The X, Y, Width and Height variables give you enough information to create a `CGRect` with the same size as the element:

```
CGRect editFrame = CGRectMake(233.0, 6.0, 67, 32);
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't really sure about the format of the points, that explains a lot to me! (I'll accept this answer in 8 minutes :P)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create a CGRect you can usually reference other objects inside IB. Referencing the frame property that a lot of objects have can be an easy way to do it. For example, self.view.frame returns a CGRect that you can store a pointer to or extract information from, according to your needs.